# How to close connection on Mailcore2?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mailcore2

I see mailcore2 has something like:

```
[_session disconnectOperation]
```

but I do not know how to implement that.

How can I disconnect from server (close connection)?

Answer (score 1):

And found it:

```
[_session.disconnectOperation start:^(NSError * error){}];
```